# Measure real size of object with Calibrated Camera opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

i am completing my thesis related opencv.
I want to measure real size of object (mm) with single camera but i have problem with **convert the camera's natural units (pixels) and the real world units**!!! 
After calibrate camera, i have:

1. Camera matrix (3x3)
2. Distortion coefficients
3. Extrinsic parameters [rotation vector(1x3) + translation vector(1x3)]

I have read following link but i can't find out formula to convert unit.
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Example about measure size of object
[image]

Any sugguestion???
Thanks so much.

Comment: But you need at least distance to object

Comment: I have fixed distance from camera to object. It is 450mm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need the distance to the object to obtain 3D coordinates from pixels. A possible workflow would be:

1. Rectify the image using the distortion parameters, i.e., correct the distortion caused by the camera.
2. Deproject the pixels into 3D points in the camera coordinate frame using the camera matrix. For this you can multiply the inverse of the 3x3 camera matrix with a vector containing the pixels `[pixel_x, pixel_y, 1]^T`. If you multiply the result `[x', y', 1]^T` with the depth, i.e., the z-component you obtain the 3D point in the camera coordinate frame.
3. Transform the point from the camera coordinate frame into the world coordinate frame using the extrinsics parameters.

Obtaining the depth values from an image alone is not possible. The only option is to use some additional information. Maybe your object is placed on a table and you know the distance between the camera and the table.

To measure distances between the camera and a table or even the object itself you could use Aruco markers, which are also available within openCV.

Comment: About 3: I have got extrinsic parameters but that is rotation vector not rotation matrix and i can't not convert vector to matrix with cvRodrigues in order to Transform the point from the camera coordinate frame into the world coordinate frame. I have rvecs. 

Mat rotationMatrix(3, 3, CV_64F);
Rodrigues(rvecs, rotationMatrix);
cout << "Rotation Matrix: " << endl << rotationMatrix << endl;

Comment: I don't understand your question/ problem. But if you are only interested in the size of an object you can skip step 3.

Comment: I have calibrated camera and i have measured size of object with natural units (pixel) but I want measure real size of object with physical units (mm). So, How? 
Thanks

Comment: Assuming your object is a rectangle, like in your picture, you have to transform the pixel coordinates of the corners of the object into 3D coordinates using step 2 (and maybe step 1 if image is not rectified). The size of the object is the distance between the corner points in 3D coordinates.